# Xcode Game Center connection error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, game-center

I'm setting up a Game Center connection in my game to report high scores and achievements. It is all working actually (leaderboards are displayed, scores are reported, and achievements are achieved) so it seems the connection is working.
But I still get the "add the Game Center feature to your app id" error in when I enable Game Center in Xcode under the capabilities tab
Gamecenter connection error Picture
[Gamecenter connection error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMumh.png)

I'm still new to apple development but there seems to be something wrong with the connection between my app and iTunes connect even tho:

- I set up my app witch matching bundle id
- Game Center is enabled on the iTunes connect features page
- Game Center is enabled on developer app identifiers page
- the Game Center feature is active and working

What exactly does the error mean? and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out with the help of the Apple developer support, they told me I did nothing wrong and it it just a glich, but the app should still be working (and is actually accepted to the App Store by now)

Comment: There's also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700082/xcode-error-add-the-game-center-feature-to-your-app-id   (in which turning ON the Push Notification feature immediately above Game Center and then turning Push Notification OFF does the job).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while doing my Mobile Game.

This steps made it work, for me.

Go to capabilities on your project [and you should find something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gneIL.png)

Turn on the [push notification capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxDmN.png)

And once you done this, turn the push notification off and turn on the gamecenter [just like i've done in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLGLC.png)

This worked for me :D