# Xcode error "Add the Game Center feature to your App ID"

Tags: ios, xcode, gamekit

This thing showed up red. How do I fit it?

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Solution:

Enable Push Notification on that same screen. Then turn off Push Notification.

It's a bug in Xcode.

Comment: God bless! This was driving me up the wall